# data factory consume data sets with different time intervals

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am new to using data factory and have two pipelines.

- **Pipeline A** contains an **Activity A** that runs once every `30 minutes` and generates a **Dataset A**. Activity A is a copy activity that generates .csv file in data lake storage.
- **Pipeline B** contains an **Activity B** that runs once every `24 hours` and needs **Dataset A**.

> - I could have avoided the consumption of Dataset A in Pipeline B in the data factory representation.. however I am afraid that Pipeline A might start running and corrupt the dataset while Pipeline B is active and running.

How can i make **Pipeline B** consume **Dataset A** ?

- The only way I could think of generating this is recreating the **Activity A** in **Pipeline B** and redoing the same task as Pipeline A :(

My question is : Is there a way I can do this without duplicating the activity in the second pipeline ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is ADFv1?

That being the case, complex dependency between activities is pretty hard to achieve. Mostly what is supported in v1 is "Activity A produces Dataset A, Activity B consumes Dataset A" so Activity B won't start until Activity A completes. Note that these activities do not have to be in the same pipeline.

You don't say what your activities are doing but assuming Activity A copies something to a data lake store folder and then Activity B copies everything in that folder somewhere else; I'm pretty sure that you can just set Activity B up with Dataset A as input and B will not run until the relevant slices are available - see [Model datasets with different frequencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution#model-datasets-with-different-frequencies).

However, if Activity A is updating something in data lake store that Activity B is consuming then there is nothing or in way of stopping Activity A from running it's next slice even if Activity B is already running. In this scenario, it may be worth considering rearchitecting your solution so that Activity A simply dumps the datasets in a staging folder and Activity B then consumes all of those to create a merged dataset.

As a final note, with the preview release of ADFv2 now available there are many more options for branching and control flow, there's even the ability to execute SSIS packages....might be options for a cleaner solution :)